# Federated log out NextAuth, Azure-Ad

Tags: reactjs, next.js, azure-active-directory, logout, next-auth

Trying to implement Federated log out with NextAuth + Azure-ad

Log in works, log out works on local only.

On production only log in works, sign out redirects me to their sign out page but fails to clear user session on return to the application.

Session still showing the user as logged in after logging out of the providerer + calling Nextauth's SignOut method - any ideas?

/sign-out-page

```
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";

import { useEffect } from "react";
export default function SignoutPage() {
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      signOut({ callbackUrl: window.location.origin });
    }, 4000);
  }, []);

  return <p>Please wait while we sign you out!</p>;
}
```

sign out button (Azure AD provider)

```
    <a  href={`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https://staging.webportal.ca/sign-out-page`}>
            <Button color="red" uppercase fullWidth>
              Log Out
            </Button>
          </a>
```

and in the azure AD admin
[image]

```
https://staging.webportal.ca/sign-out-page
```

Comment: Will need to use a custom api on next.js to hit the providers IDP logout endpoint with the right credentials -> then use nextauths signOut() method to delete the client side session. 

still working on the api part